# iOS adding more layer into uiview affecting performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uiview, cashapelayer

I am using `CAShapeLayer` for complex drawing purpose.

I am creating 100's of `CAShapeLayer` objets and adding them as a sublayers into my `mainview` layer. It's affecting my application performance. How can i improve it? I didn't use `CGContext` for drawing since it has some forbidden for my complexity drawing. Please help me.

Comment: It would be good to give a lot more information. Are these static images, or are they animated around? In what way is it affecting the application performance? For static images, drawing directly into a single CALayer with CGContext you can exactly the same, and it should be much faster, so why do you think that is not possible?

Comment: @fishnear : i am drawing complex line paths by use of 'CAShapelayer' and it's not an images and it's not animated.At certain point i have to delete the particular part of the drawing.So if i use 'CAShapelayer' it will be easy to remove that particular drawing points.That's why i am using multiple objects of 'CAShapelayer' instead of single layer.

Comment: Drawing hundreds of complex line paths is not going to happen in the blink of an eye. So if you draw them in the main thread, it is going to affect ui performance. I suggest to draw them in a background thread in separate CALayer's

Comment: @fishinear i have tried as per your suggestion(Drawing in background thread).But drawing to appear at first time it's taking long time.So this will not workout.Any way thanks a lot for suggestion.